# Reordering is not working when scrollable=true in PrimeNG datatable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am trying to use `reorderableColumns` and `scrollable` properties together in my `p-datatable`.

But it seems that it is not working as expected. When we try to drag the columns it is not moving. If we remove scrollable property from code, then everything will work fine.

This is my oneline code

```
<p-dataTable id="empListGrid" [value]="list" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,30,50,100]" [responsive]="true" [reorderableColumns]="true" [editable]="true" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="1200px">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the latest version of PrimeNG? I found [this issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/238), which seems to be resolved by now.

Comment: i am using 2.0.0 version of primeng.